# CSS variables only for certain properties

Tags: css, variables

There is a way to specify the usage of variables only for certain properties.
It is used to not overwrite say a padding with a color variable.

So if you would declare a variables like this:

> --myColor: red

you **could not** use the variable in a padding like this:

```
.p {
    /* should NOT be possible */
    padding: var(--myColor);
}
```

Could someone **help me out with the name of this feature**, please?

So, basically the code will be more complex then --myColor: red.

I think I remember something like an object structure (but I might be wrong):

`myColor { color: red; elements: color }`

Comment: You can do something similar with sass, but this isn't possible in raw CSS.

Comment: *but when you declare it you can specify what kind of css properties this variable can be used for* --> there is no such feature with CSS variables

Comment: maybe it wasn't an object, I can't remember exactly, I was looking briefly on a blog post talking about it. But I cannot find that article and cannot remember the name of the feature either. It was a CSS native feature. Probably a recent one...

Comment: @JamesWhiteley It is used to not overwrite say a padding with a color variable.

Comment: @aldobsom you cannot declare CSS variables as objects. You can embed variables inside each other (e.g. `--gradient: linear-gradient(--inner-whatever)`), but not what you want to do. Look into sass if you want a richer CSS experience.

Comment: You can use `var()` in modern browsers: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

However check support and make a decision to use it based on your requirements with regards to supporting browsers.

Comment: @OKsure I updated my question so it is more clear now ( I hope :) )

Comment: It sounds like you may be confused with the mechanism for [custom properties fallback values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties#Custom_property_fallback_values), where you can write things like `var(--myColor, 0)` if --myColor does not exist. Or was that not what you were thinking of?

Comment: @MrLister: your suggestion with fallback values is good, but not what I was looking for. I am pretty sure there is a way to declare what kind of properties the variables should work with in advance, not after the fact.

Comment: You might be able to get type safety from a static linter tool but I don't think CSS has much in the way of exception handling so there's nothing to stop it from accepting a color value for a position property AFAIK.

Comment: No matter what I type in google, I cannot find what I'm looking for :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, see here explanations https://youtu.be/3IUxyBx_PnM?t=1660

```
CSS.registerProperty({
    name: "--stop-color",
    syntax: "<color>",
    inherits: false,
    initialValue: "black"

})
```

> it's actually Houdini CSS